# Allow users to select and change icons in a multi company program

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I am developing a C# program that will allow the users to enter multiple companies, and I am trying to allow the users to use an icon (as well as the name of the company in the taskbar) for each company to help them differ easily between them.

So far I have the following code, which shows a picturebox of the icon to confirm it is the correct image, but when I run the program it crashes with an out-of-memory-exception after changing the image 3 or 4 times. After reading solutions to similar questions on this site I have tried to dispose the image but can't seem to get it to work correctly:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "R:\\rightsort fulfilment\\charity icons";
  openFileDialog1.Title = "Choose an Icon";
  openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
  openFileDialog1.Filter = "Icon Files|*.ico";

  if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
  {
    txtIcon.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(txtIcon.Text);
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
  }
  else
  {
    txtIcon.Text = "";
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I *think* you must have something else going on. I don't see anything wrong with your code and certainly you shouldn't be running out of memory after loading only 3 or 4 icons!

Comment: congrats on being the 300,000th exact question tagged with c# ;)

Comment: So I don't need to worry about disposing the image? I do have SQL Connections in the program as well, I thought all connections were closed after use, but I will check again just in case...

Comment: I would add that this code doesn't dispose any image. Maybe you had a bad Icon file?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I have tried to use the dispose method, but couldn't find the right place for it to work and therefore removed it again.

Answer (score 2):

Image class inherited from IDisposable. You need to call Dispose method every time you replace it with new image to release resources.

However I don't know if this is the source of your problem. You also can try to run memory profiler and see where and how exactly memory gets allocated.

Comment: Implementation is form of inheritance with limitation to inherit interface only

Comment: I think @victor.t has hit the nail on the head, I just don't know how to fit the dispose method into my code. I've tried using it in varying ways but I get error messages whenever I think I'm getting somewhere!  :)

Comment: if(pictureBox1.Image != null)
 pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(txtIcon.Text);

Answer (score 1):

I would try disposing the old image in the picture control. Something like this:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    txtIcon.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    Image oldImage = pictureBox1.Image;
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(txtIcon.Text);
    if (oldImage != null)
    {
        oldImage.Dispose();
    }
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I tried this but still had the same problem. I had a little tweak around with it but got the same result. As mentioned by Matt, I must have something else going on in the background that's causing the crash.